# Remove HTML attributes from string

Tags: c#, html, .net

Is there any way of removing all html attributes in a given string in .net?

**Input:**

```
Hello onclick="alert(1)" onfocus="alert(2_" onblur="haihu(84384)" World
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
```

Comment: What is HTML here?

Comment: I can't see any _html attribute_ in your example

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers to begin with. ;) To be serious, try using a regex to detect the `="..."` delimiting an attribute and remove everything it detect and everything in front of it until you hit the previous space, since the attributes will need at least one space between them. Other option is to actually create a HTML element from the string and remove all the attributes using the Element methods.

Comment: I think that the above commenters are trying to say is we would need to see where this is coming from.  There is no HTML string that would contain Hello, then a bunch of parameters and then World.  Can you give us the full HTML string you would be passing?

Comment: Better try to explain what you want to achieve. Are you saving string entered by user in web page and trying to protect other users from javascript injections? Then HTML escaping is easier solution.

Comment: Hi there Nitish, welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like the formatting of your code is missing elements that people would normally use to identify the input code you provided as HTML. I suspect that you meant something like this:

```Hello <a onclick="alert(1)" onfocus="alert(2_" onblur="haihu(84384)">World</a>```

If this is the case, can you correct your question so that I can answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static string StripHTMLTags(string inputstring)
{
   return Regex.Replace(inputstring, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```